# Could "code" in chat (markdown with backquotes) change the background like on the main site?

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown, design

In chatting, I've taken to using bold to format code.  This is because it does not stand out very well if the only thing that changes is a fixed-width font.  For instance:

[image: Demonstrate bold is better than fixed-width with no background change]

But it seems that if CSS were applied to use a fixed width font and change the background color, that would be a better solution.  I'm not sure of the entire implications, but here's a test:

[image: With CSS applied for background]

Comment: Code appears more bold if it is bolded (**`**\`code\`**`**), and `text-shadow: 1px 0 #000` is applied to it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zvVBG.png

Comment: yes please this would be really helpful!

Comment: Basically, hearing something official from SE staff on this would be awesome.

Comment: Ditto. If I interpret the existing answers correctly, they allow me to highlight the code for myself. But when I'm chatting and posting code *I want everyone else to easily distinguish code from everything else, regardless if they bothered to install some script or another prosthesis*. This issue should definitely be fixed on the server side.

Answer (score 8):

I have written a UserScript that automatically highlights code in chat messages. Example:

[image]

More information and download links can be found here:

> [Highlight Code in Chat - Highlights <code> elements contained in chat messages](https://stackapps.com/questions/3922/highlight-code-in-chat-highlights-code-elements-contained-in-chat-messages)

Comment: Could you also add `chat.se/transcript/*` and highlight `<pre>` as well?

Comment: Cool.  Having a user script is nice as a prototype to test the idea, but a lot of people use chat without extensions.  Something like this that affects the commonly perceived display isn't really a "power user" chat feature, but rather seems it should be built in...

Comment: @LoremIpsum: Done.

Comment: @HostileFork: Yes, but the impression I get from the OP is that those who *need* the feature are the ones who would be able to easily install the UserScript.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Thanks, but the `<pre>` blocks are not highlighted though...

Comment: @LoremIpsum: Hmm... I'll fix that shortly. Sorry about that oversight.

Comment: @LoremIpsum: Sorry for the long delay - I have now updated the script.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a similar effect with a user style:

```css
@-moz-document domain("chat.stackexchange.com") {
    div.message pre, div.message code {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        padding: 0.2em;
    }
}
```

Tweak the colour, opacity, and padding to your liking.

Prerequisite: [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/) browser add-on

- [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)
- [for Chromium/Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe)
- [for Opera](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/stylish/)
- [for Safari](http://sobolev.us/stylish/)